# How to correctly stop pyqt5 QThread?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

There is a program for pyqt5. It has a thread (qthread) in which you need to perform some action with a certain front end. I used QThread.msleep to define this period, and the flag that came out of the while cycle.
But if the period is long, then it will take a long time to wait for the exit from the loop, and I want to finish it as soon as I click on the button in the GUI (but not kill, start again soon).
The source code is pretty standard here, I need ideas.
An example of an exaggerated class for a separate thread.

```
class intrhead(QObject):
    ...
    def run(self):
        while(flag):
            ...
            QThread.msleep(period)
```

Comment: "I used QThread.msleep to define this period": what period? "The source code is pretty standard": standard for what? Please be more clear and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we are not clairvoyants, if we don't really understand what you're doing we cannot give you "ideas", and, for what's worth, StackOverflow is not about "giving ideas", but *answers*.

Comment: You setup isn't clear to me. Do you want to perform a certain action repeatedly with a certain waiting time between the repeats?

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is to split the period.